# How to simplify my javascript code(ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use ajax in my code. I have to call connectHost() from $('SyncDataPort0') to $('SyncDataPort5'),

```
function connectHost()
{
    ajaxFrame($('SyncDataPort0').value, getConnectStatus);
}

function getConnectStatus(transport) 
{
    try {
        rs = transport.responseText;
        if(rs == 'OK') {
            //$('SyncDataState0').innerHTML = 'ok';
            addStateMsg($('ConnectTest'),getMsg('msgConnectOk'));
        } else //NOT OK

        addStateMsg($('ConnectTest'),getMsg('msgConnectNotOkResult').replace('%s',rs));
    }catch(e){alert(e)};
}

function ajaxFrame(url, pars, onCompleteFun)
{
if (3 in arguments)
    addStateMsg(arguments[3],getMsg('msgDataSending'),0);

new Ajax.Request(url,
{
    method:'post',
    parameters:pars,
    onComplete: function(transport)
    {
        var rs = transport.responseText;
        if('logout' == rs)
            location.href='/index.php?menu=logout';
        else if('' == rs)
        {
            //do nothing
        }else
            onCompleteFun.apply(this,[transport]);
    },
    onFailure:function()
    {
        debug('Load Data Failure!');
    }
});
return true;
}
```

The question is how can i implement the function without reproducing the getConnectStatus
callback function???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an inline function declaration, you can refer to variables in the parent scope and you can pass the port to your `connectHost()` function.

```
function connectHost(portNum)
{
    ajaxFrame($('SyncDataPort' + portNum).value, function(transport) {
        // you can refer to portNum here in the callback
        try {
            rs = transport.responseText;
            if(rs == 'OK') {
                //$('SyncDataState0').innerHTML = 'ok';
                addStateMsg($('ConnectTest'),getMsg('msgConnectOk'));
            } else //NOT OK

            addStateMsg($('ConnectTest'),getMsg('msgConnectNotOkResult').replace('%s',rs));
        } catch(e) {alert(e)};
    });
}
```

---

If you want `getConnectStatus()` to still be its own function, then you can use an inline stub function like this:

```
function connectHost(portNum)
{
    ajaxFrame($('SyncDataPort' + portNum).value, function(transport) {
        getConnectStatus(transport, portNum);
    });
}
```

And `getConnectStatus()` will have the `portNum` as the second argument.  You can pass as many arguments through to the callback as you like this way.

---

If `getConnectStatus()` needs the value of `this` preserved, then you would do this:

```
function connectHost(portNum)
{
    ajaxFrame($('SyncDataPort' + portNum).value, function(transport) {
        getConnectStatus.call(this, transport, portNum);
    });
}
```